# I face this problem during run query with union all.. 3653 All select-lists do not contain the same number of expressions

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(STATE_DATE AS DATE))* 100 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST( STATE_DATE AS DATE)) AS MONTH_,
    COUNT(MDN) as CustomerBase
FROM 
    PMP_AVEW.FCT_SUBS_DLY_SNAP
WHERE 
    STATE_DATE between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31'
    AND STATUS IN ('Active','Suspended')
    AND DSHB_STS_REASON NOT IN ('CMP','OCR')
GROUP BY 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT SR_NUMBER) AS Number_OF_Complain
FROM 
    PMP_AVEW.FCT_SR_TXN
WHERE 
    SR_STATUS <> 'Cancelled'
    AND TYPE_OF_NETWORK_OUTAGE IS NULL
    AND OUTAGE_TICKET_ID IS NULL
    AND COALESCE(FT_CONFIRM_FLG, 'K') <> 'Y'
    AND CAST(SR_OPEN_DT AS DATE) between '2021-12-01' and '2021-12-31'
    AND SR_TYPE IN ('Technical Services','GPON Technical Services')
```

Comment: You **cannot** do a `UNION ALL` on two `SELECT` queries when the first one returns **two**, but the second one only returns **one** column. The number of columns (and their datatypes) **must match** for a `UNION` / `UNION ALL` to be applied

Comment: There are 2 columns in the 1st part of the UNION ALL, only 1 in the 2nd part

Comment: It seems you want to JOIN these two aggregate relations rather than UNION. Since you are not projecting the date in the second (maybe because each currently returns a single row) you could CROSS JOIN. You could make each query a Derived Table expression in order to join, e.g. `SELECT * FROM (first query) A CROSS JOIN (second query) B;` or use CTE (WITH clause).

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` (and `UNION ALL`) is a set operator, it appends two sets of results, of same type. Therefore both queries 'unioned' are required to have the same number of columns and same types in respective columns. Your first query returns two columns, and the second one returns one.